# How to compile LLVM with a specific target

Tags: compilation, llvm

For some reason the compile speed of LLVM is extremely slow on my Mac, and based on my observation most of the time is spend on compiling the different target in **llvm/lib/Target**.

However, the only target I need is X86, so I'm wondering is there a way to specify the target I want to compile so that the LLVM will only compile that target and save a lot of time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass [`-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86`](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#llvm-specific-variables) to the initial `cmake` invocation.

Comment: and how to pass that?

Comment: @C0deZ you would pass that to `cmake`, like `cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 ...` in step 4 here: https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#quick-start